# Кроссбраузерная верстка (ie,ff)

Tags: html, вёрстка

Есть шаблончик, в опере он отображаеться нормально, в мозиле сверху появляется черная полоса, посмотреть можно на скрине здесь:

[image: снимок]

Смотрел через firebug, там вообще все содержимое из `<head>` перенеслось в `<body>`, хотя в самом html это не так. В ie тоже есть эта черная полоса, плюсом ко всему поехала верстка на странице там, вот скрин:

[image: снимок]

(Насчет прозрачности png я знаю, это не проблема сейчас.)

Сам сайтик можно пощупать здесь: http://bit.ly/pWiTZ5.

Comment: Вся проблема была в том что файл шаблона был сохранен в utf-8 с bom, из за этого и появлялась черная полоса сверху и ехала верстка в ie

Comment: Мы не будем ходить щупать сайтик, особенно по сокращенной ссылке. Хотите ответ — код в студию.

Answer (score 2):

[Качаем](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css), подключаем - смотрим.

Comment: p.s. По поводу сайта. header б!@#$! большой чересчур. Я бы перепланировал разметку на вашем месте. А еще лучше перепродумать всю планировку.

Comment: normalize.css не помог, а насчет веса, я бы и рад переделать, так сами картинки весят много, начну уменьшать размер, в качеству потеряю сильно

Comment: попробуй найди reset.css он должен исправить ситуацию

Answer (score 1):

> Смотрел через firebug, там вообще все содержимое из `<head>` перенеслось в `<body>`

`head` будет автоматически закрыт при парсинге и начат `body` как только встретит тег, который должен принадлежать body. Так что проверь `head` на наличие посторонних тегов.

Comment: там под вопросом есть коммент от топикастера. проблема была в bom

Comment: @PashaPash, не заметил... Но вообще, вроде браузеры bom умеют обрабатывать?

Comment: нет. BOM - отметка в файле, указывающая кодировку. вебсервер должен ее вырезать - он же возвращает не файл, а содержимое. Браузер ждет доктайпа в самом начале документа, не находит его там - и показывает черт знает что. Т.е. это был глюк вебсервера, который бом не вырезал.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой совет. Убери надписи с картинок и сделай их обычным текстом. Они ужасно смотрятся. Будет более гладкий шрифт, и размер картинок уменьшится.